# Add nodes from xml properties to soap message with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, properties, addition

Please I need your help,

XML: I Have this SOAP Message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
 <Service>
  <ServiceRequest>
   <tag3>value3</tag3>
  </ServiceRequest>
 </Service>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XSL: I need to add nodes from xml properties. I try with this xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<xsl:variable name="props">
<properties>
 <property>
  <key>tag1</key>
  <value>value1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <key>tag2</key>
  <value>value2</value>
 </property>
</properties>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ServiceRequest">
<xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$props/properties/property">
   <xsl:variable name="tag" select="key" />
   <xsl:element name="{$tag}">
    <xsl:value-of select="value" />
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML after XSL: I need a result like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
 <Service>
  <ServiceRequest>
   <tag1>value1</tag1>
   <tag2>value2</tag2>
   <tag3>value3</tag3>
  </ServiceRequest>
 </Service>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But the XSL does'n work. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the XSLT has a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, so the `properties` and `property` element are in that namespace, and so `select="$props/properties/property"` does not match anything because they are looking for elements in the null namespace.

The default namespace seems not to be necessary, so the easiest fix is just to drop it.

Another possible problem is that the `$prop` variable contains a XML fragment and not a node-set - this means that it needs to be converted to a node set before being used in the `for-each` - this is done with XSLT extension functions that are implementation dependent.

Using the Microsoft XSLT processor the correct XSLT looks like this:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" standalone="no" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:variable name="props">
    <properties>
      <property>
        <key>tag1</key>
        <value>value1</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <key>tag2</key>
        <value>value2</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ServiceRequest">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($props)/properties/property">
        <xsl:variable name="tag" select="key" />
        <xsl:element name="{$tag}">
          <xsl:value-of select="value" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```